# accesing Jupyter running in AWS - getting certificate error accessing it

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am installing Jupyter notebook in AWS-ec2 as per this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6

### I am stuck at the point where I try to access the notebook from my laptop and get the below error:

> [E 06:33:24.239 NotebookApp] Exception in callback (, .null_wrapper at 0x7f5689fcdd90>)
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py",
>   line 888, in start
>           handler_func(fd_obj, events)
>         File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>           return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py",
>   line 276, in accept_handler
>           callback(connection, address)
>         File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py",
>   line 264, in _handle_connection
>           do_handshake_on_connect=False)
>         File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py",
>   line 517, in ssl_wrap_socket
>           context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
>         File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py",
>   line 494, in ssl_options_to_context
>           context.load_cert_chain(ssl_options['certfile'], ssl_options.get('keyfile', None))
>
> ### PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

My jupyter notebook config is below

```
> c = get_config()
> 
> # Kernel config c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always in your notebook
> 
> # Notebook config c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' #location of your certificate file
> c.NotebookApp.ip = '*' c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  #so that
> the ipython notebook does not opens up a browser by default
> c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:262....your hash here.........65f' 
> #edit this with the SHA hash that you generated after typing in Step 9
> # This is the port we opened in Step 3. c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Comment: seems permission denied when trying to load certfile. Do you have permissions to access /home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem? Also, shouldn't the path be /home/ec2-user/... ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Jupyter notebook config file that you have shared in the question above make a few changes by following the steps shown below.

To configure the jupyter config file thoroughly, follow these steps:

```
cd ~/.jupyter/

vi jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

[image]

Insert this at the *beginning* of the document:

```
c = get_config()
# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always in your notebook
# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' #location of your certificate file
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  #so that the ipython notebook does not opens up a browser by default
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d'  #the encrypted password we generated above
# Set the port to 8888, the port we set up in the AWS EC2 set-up
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

Once you enter these above lines, make sure you **save** the config file before you exit the vi editor!
And also, most importantly remember to replace sha1:98ff0e580111:12798c72623a6eecd54b51c006b1050f0ac1a62d with your password!

Note that since in the above config file we have given port as 8888, the same is added in the security group. (Custom TCP type,TCP protocol, port range as 8888 and source is custom)

Now you are good to go!

Type the following command:

```
screen
```

This command will allow you to create a separate screen for just your Jupyter process logs while you continue to do other work on the ec2 instance.

And now start the jupyter notebook by typing the command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

To visit the jupyter notebook from the browser in your local machine:

Your EC2 instance will have a long url, like this:

ec2-52-39-239-66.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Visit that URL in you browser locally. Make sure to have https at the beginning and port 8888 at the end as shown below.

https://ec2-52-39-239-66.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/

This should get it running.